Windows button + "." to open Emoji's pop-up windows makes Windows 10 go mad! There is any solution?
When I open emoji'frame using " Win + ." (in ex. writing in Edge's folder's rename/naming field, but also in many others cases) the Taskbar start blinking ( cause of conflict between opening of Start Menu and the shortcut ) and the emoji's frame, that it opens in right low corner of the screen, don't work with the text-field (if a emoji is selected is not added).
(Normally I "recover" using esc button).
      The only option is to right-click on text field and select emoji there.

(!) In contextual menu the shortcut is mentioned.

There is any solution to correct this shell behavior?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
